# DllNotFoundException:Unable to load DLL 'FirebaseCppApp-6_13_0

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

using firebase authentication SDK unity

getting this error:

DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'FirebaseCppApp-6_13_0': The specified module could not be found.
at Firebase.AppUtilPINVOKE+SWIGExceptionHelper.SWIGRegisterExceptionCallbacks_AppUtil (Firebase.AppUtilPINVOKE+SWIGExceptionHelper+ExceptionDelegate applicationDelegate, Firebase.AppUtilPINVOKE+SWIGExceptionHelper+ExceptionDelegate arithmeticDelegate, Firebase.AppUtilPINVOKE+SWIGExceptionHelper+ExceptionDelegate divideByZeroDelegate, Firebase.AppUtilPINVOKE+SWIGExceptionHelper+ExceptionDelegate indexOutOfRangeDelegate, Firebase.AppUtilPINVOKE+SWIGExceptionHelper+ExceptionDelegate invalidCastDelegate, Firebase.AppUtilPINVOKE+SWIGExceptionHelper+ExceptionDelegate invalidOperationDelegate, Firebase.AppUtilPINVOKE+SWIGExceptionHelper+ExceptionDelegate ioDelegate, Firebase.AppUtilPINVOKE+SWIGExceptionHelper+ExceptionDelegate nullReferenceDelegate, Firebase.AppUtilPINVOKE+SWIGExceptionHelper+ExceptionDelegate outOfMemoryDelegate, Firebase.AppUtilPINVOKE+SWIGExceptionHelper+ExceptionDelegate overflowDelegate, Firebase.AppUtilPINVOKE+SWIGExceptionHelper+ExceptionDelegate systemExceptionDelegate) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at Firebase.AppUtilPINVOKE+SWIGExceptionHelper..cctor () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at Firebase.AppUtilPINVOKE..cctor () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at Firebase.AppUtil.SetLogFunction (Firebase.LogUtil+LogMessageDelegate arg0) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at Firebase.LogUtil..ctor () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at Firebase.LogUtil..cctor () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at Firebase.FirebaseApp..cctor () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at LoginHandler.Start () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
Rethrow as TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Firebase.AppUtilPINVOKE.SWIGExceptionHelper' threw an exception.
  at Firebase.AppUtilPINVOKE..cctor () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at Firebase.AppUtil.SetLogFunction (Firebase.LogUtil+LogMessageDelegate arg0) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at Firebase.LogUtil..ctor () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at Firebase.LogUtil..cctor () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at Firebase.FirebaseApp..cctor () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at LoginHandler.Start () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
Rethrow as TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Firebase.AppUtilPINVOKE' threw an exception.
  at Firebase.AppUtil.SetLogFunction (Firebase.LogUtil+LogMessageDelegate arg0) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at Firebase.LogUtil..ctor () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at Firebase.LogUtil..cctor () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at Firebase.FirebaseApp..cctor () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at LoginHandler.Start () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
Rethrow as TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Firebase.LogUtil' threw an exception.
  at Firebase.FirebaseApp..cctor () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at LoginHandler.Start () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
Rethrow as TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Firebase.FirebaseApp' threw an exception.
  at LoginHandler.Start () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0

(Filename: currently not available on il2cpp Line: -1)

Answer (score 0):

So I was getting the same error but with FirebaseCppApp 7.1.0
*DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'FirebaseCppApp-7_1_0.'*

Under Unity navigate in the menu bar to *Assets -> Project Settings -> Player -> Target Architectures and Uncheck ARMv7*.

[image: Project Settings]

After that navigate to the External Dependency Manager and choose Force Resolve. Unity should then resolve the dependencies and your app should be good to go.

[image: External Dependency Manager]

Answer (score 0):

I think you might have mixed dependencies. You should check the maven url located in

*Assets/Plugins/Android/mainTemplate.gradle*

If you can't find it, go to Publishing Settings to create it. Maven URL looks like:

`maven { url (unityProjectPath + "/Assets/GeneratedLocalRepo/Firebase/m2repository") // Assets/Firebase/Editor/AppDependencies.xml:22, Assets/Firebase/Editor/RemoteConfigDependencies.xml:20 }`

In my case, all dependencies like firebase-app, firebase-auth, firebase-analytics are not located in */Assets/GeneratedLocalRepo/Firebase/m2repository*.
I import these SDK dependencies using the TGZ file downloaded from the firebase website, because when I import using the SDK/donet3 of the tutorial I get an error. So I have to change the maven url to where the loaded dependencies are located.