# Unity Android Build Errors due to Firebase Libraries

Tags: android, firebase, unity-game-engine, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I am building an Unity app for android using Firebase Authentication and Firestore. It runs alright in the Editor and in the desktop build.

However, when I build for Android, I get the error below:

> Autoconnected Player DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'FirebaseCppApp-8_8_0'. Tried the load the following dynamic libraries: Unable to load dynamic library 'FirebaseCppApp-8_8_0' because of 'Failed to open the requested dynamic library (0x06000000) dlerror() = dlopen failed: library "FirebaseCppApp-8_8_0" not found

Please assist.

Comment: Please try with the solution explained in stackoverflow URL https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61359478/dllnotfoundexceptionunable-to-load-dll-firebasecppapp-6-13-0

Comment: Tried it but it didn't work. When I force resolve, I cannot build and I get "exception execution failed for task ':launcher:checkreleaseduplicateclasses'" and when I delete resolved libraries, it builds but I get the error that DllException problem. I even completely removed Firebase (I think I did) but issue still persists

Answer (score 0):

It seems like conflicting firebase dependencies cause this. To resolve this

1. Delete everything firebase (auth, crashlytics, messaging etc)
2. Import these again from unity package provided by firebase
3. Right Click anywhere in project -> External dependency manager -> Force Resolve